# Google Apps Script Multiple Search with Drive App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I hope I have searched good enough in order to ask this questions.

I have this code to clean up some default files in our team drive, if somebody got them in sync by accident...

In this case desktop.ini

```
function cleanup(){
  var folderID = 'FOLDERID';
  var search = 'title Contains "desktop.ini"';
  var fileIDs = [];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);
  while (files.hasNext()){
      files.next().setTrashed(true);
    }
   Logger.log('fileIDs.length + ' files have been moved to trash');
}
```

Is there a way to add multiple hits in one search?

What if I would want to add other files like "thumbs.db" or from the mac guys ".DS_Store". Do I need to search for everything individually or is there a .gitignore way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? When you want to retrieve the files with the filenames which contained "desktop.ini", "thumbs.db" and ".DS_Store" in one search using `DriveApp.searchFiles()`, you can achieve it using `or` operator as follows.

```
var search = 'title contains "desktop.ini" or title contains "thumbs.db" or title contains ".DS_Store"';
```

#### Reference :

- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

Comment: Thx this indeed solved my issue, next time i will look a bit more thorough.